# Firing a command in a existing command Prompt. using another .bat file

Tags: batch-file, minecraft

I am trying to make a .bat file fire a command in a existing command prompt (which is running a Minecraft server.) I hope to shortcut to it so I can link it to windows 10 task scheduler for automatic scheduled tasks. Such as running a command to save map files every hour and restart every day at 3am.

I've spent two hours googling an answer with no success.

Comment: You can't make two commands run concurrently in the same cmd window. While Java is running, it is being executed and displaying server info, therefore nothing else will run until java exists, via stop or forced exit

Comment: To the windows batch command processor your whole minecraft server is a single command. It has no idea about its internals such as restart or save. Your server should provide APIs or its own scripting to do things like that. Those APIs may be utilized with plugins or similar - something like this: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/jenorestart-for-bukkit-spigot-1-8.6524/